# Sending variable to email

Tags: php, email, variables

I want sending a html page including variable to email using `PHPMailer`.
this my content to send :

```
    $mailContent = "<h3>Mohon persetujuan</h3>
    <p>Dengan ini saya mengajukan pembuatan system guna penunjang pekerjaan. adapun rinciannya sebagai berikut :</p></br>
    <table width=100% border=0 style=margin-left:20px>
  <tr>
    <td width=30%>Nama Pemohon </td>
    <td width=70%>: $user</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jabatan Pemohon </td>
    <td>: $bagian</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nama System </td>
    <td>: $system</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Latar Belakang </td>
    <td>: $latar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>
    <p>Mohon untuk disetujui supaya pembuatan system bisa segera direalisasikan</p></br>
    <a href=http://bms-kds.freemyip.com:8081/system?token=$token >Setujui</a>";
$mail->Body = $mailContent;
```

My variable want to send is $token. 
how can i get variable "$token" in email ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose href value in quotation. Your message is already in `"` do enclose href value in `'`

```
  $mailContent = "<h3>Mohon persetujuan</h3>
    <p>Dengan ini saya mengajukan pembuatan system guna penunjang pekerjaan. adapun rinciannya sebagai berikut :</p></br>
    <table width=100% border=0 style=margin-left:20px>
  <tr>
    <td width=30%>Nama Pemohon </td>
    <td width=70%>: $user</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jabatan Pemohon </td>
    <td>: $bagian</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nama System </td>
    <td>: $system</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Latar Belakang </td>
    <td>: $latar</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</br>
    <p>Mohon untuk disetujui supaya pembuatan system bisa segera direalisasikan</p></br>
    <a href='http://bms-kds.freemyip.com:8081/system?token=$token' >Setujui</a>";
$mail->Body = $mailContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @B.Desai suggested. You need to enclose href value in the quotation.

You can also try like this

```
<a href='http://bms-kds.freemyip.com:8081/system?token=".$token."' >Setujui</a>
```